# Macbook Air - Trying to start after a week -saw a geometrical flicker for moment - Not booting now?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, screen

[image][image][image]My Macbook Air (2018) is not booting.
Trying to start after a week. [image]
Saw a geometrical flicker for moment - Not booting now ?

Not showing any light in keypad. Showing nothing on screen or any sound.
Showing Green Light on charger plug.

Tried the tutorials of various keypresses. Not working.

Comment: What version of macOS was installed? What **exactly** have you tried so far? Can you attach any external devices and see if they respond in any way? Can you test if the screen is broken?

Comment: Performed a Power-Cycle.                                                                                                 
Also reset the System Management Controller Firmware. Dont remember the OS. What do you mean by external devices. I have iphone 5, spare windows pc etc.

Comment: If the circuitry is broken you could find that out by plugging in certain devices and see if they are being powered.  Is there anything you can think of that might have damaged the device?

Comment: Shall i try connecting with iphone 5 .....AND yes i was taking hot water steam near the device as i was suffering from possible covid.  And the weather here has turned very humid due to rain and storm. Shall i try with silicon gel packets. I just ordered a pentalobe screwdriver that helps opening the back.

Comment: I open the back side and left it for a while. I pressed the power button and i saw apple logo on screen and fan running for few seconds. Again pressed same thing.  After 48 hours again i took off the battery connector. I saw white corrosion on metal part of laptop on back panel where the power and fan resides. Tried to clean with ear bud and alcohol isopropyl. what shall try next ? I have got silica gel packets. can i lay them on exposed part ?

Comment: Added few pics.

Comment: when the logo show and fan running happened (as i mentioned above) it was not connected to power.

Comment: My macbook air started working after it kept it inside silicon gel filled packet and left for 2 weeks. It went good for 1 month ...now battery not charging beyond 10% and gets off immediately when power is not connected.