# Macbook Air not charging beyond 10 percent and does not gets on without power

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

Macbook Air 2015 A1466 .
OS is Catalina 10.15.5

I guess i allowed a update.

Macbook Air not charging beyond 10 percent and does not gets on without power. And turns off without power.

Three months back it had stopped working and had put in silicon gel bag for weeks...and it started and worked fine for 1 month.( Had mild water vapour damage after i inhaled steam near my laptop during covid!)

see prev question : [Macbook Air - Trying to start after a week -saw a geometrical flicker for moment - Not booting now?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421358/macbook-air-trying-to-start-after-a-week-saw-a-geometrical-flicker-for-moment)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking the information from your previous question and from this one together, there is a high chance that the mainboard, the battery or any other critical hardware component got damaged when you "had mild water vapour damage after i inhaled steam near my laptop". This isn't something you can fix in software, so bring it to your nearest Apple Store or Apple dealer to have it serviced.

Comment: Yes. but apple store seem to charge huge amount....and later say replace board and pay half the price of laptop. And third party repair engineers are unreliable.

Comment: can i try smc reset ....going to engineer or repair is last step. I want to be sure of the issue.

Comment: Now, my macbook is running when plugged with power. 93% to 100% charging takes lot of time . And even at 93% charge , if i remove power it shuts down immediately or in few minutes.